# ios-charts / mpandroidcharts stacked bar label total instead of values of each entry

Tags: ios, swift, mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I am using ios-charts and successfully implemented a stacked barchart.
However, I would like to display **only the total of the stack** at the top of each stacked bar, and not the value of each entry of the stacked bar.
For now, all I've been able to do is hide the individual values with chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled set to false.

Is it something that is doable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is an easier way but you could use a [`MarkerView`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/MarkerView) to accomplish this. The `MarkerView` will display for highlighted entries so after attaching it you would need to highlight all entries in the chart via one of the highlight methods:

> [`highlightValue(int xIndex, int dataSetIndex)`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.5/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.html#highlightValue(int,%20int))
>
> Highlights the value at the given x-index in the given DataSet.
>
> [`highlightValues(Highlight[] highs)`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v2.1.5/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/Chart.html#highlightValues(com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight[]))
>
> Highlights the values at the given indices in the given DataSets.

Comment: Thank you! 
I don't really get how to use a MarkerView in ios-charts as the only explanation I find is for mpandroidcharts and I don't understand how to apply it to the ios version. 
Is there any example somewhere or could you help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it does not support this. Use MarkerView or customize it yourself

Comment: I don't really get how to use a MarkerView in ios-charts as the only explanation I find is for mpandroidcharts and I don't understand how to apply it to the ios version. Is there any example somewhere or could you help me out?

Comment: Thanks! 
I have one more tiny issue, if by any change you know how to solve it if it's possible. To see the marker I have to highlight the data, do you know if there is any way NOT to change the color of the highlighted data?

Comment: @Lyra well you need take a look at the code. I dont remember. But setting the highlight color the same as normal color can be a solution

Comment: Thanks anyway, I finally found the right property to change and succeeded, using
`chartDataSet.highlightColor = UIColor.clearColor()`

Thank you for your quick answers!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by assigning a `IValueFormatter` to `BarChartData`.

Here is my implementation of `IValueFormatter`

```
class StackedBarChartValueFormatter:NSObject, IValueFormatter {

private let formatter = MKNumberFormatter()

func stringForValue(_ value: Double, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler?) -> String {
   
    guard let barchartDataEntry = entry as? BarChartDataEntry else {
        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: value)) ?? ""
    }
    
    var nonZeroYValues : [Double] = []
    barchartDataEntry.yValues?.forEach {
        
        yValue in
        
        if yValue != 0.0 {
            nonZeroYValues.append(yValue)
        }
    }
    
    if nonZeroYValues.last == value {
        return formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: entry.y)) ?? ""
    }
    else {
        return ""
    }
}

}
```

Then assign as instance of this formatter to `BarChartData`'s value formatter as below.

```
let data = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
data.setValueFormatter(StackedBarChartValueFormatter())
```

Please ignore the `MKNumberFormatter`. It is just a NumberFormatter I have created. The key is to cast `ChartDataEntry` to `BarChartDataEntry` and then return `entry.y` (which is the sum of all Y values) when it is the last item in `yValues` of `barchartDataEntry`, else an empty string.